# How to access the second element that has the same class name with Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Say, for example, on a webpage there are two columns of links. You want to web scrape all of the urls, but using BeautifulSoup and find is only locating and returning the first column.

This code finds the first column and works just fine:

```
column=content.find('div',{'class': 'className'})
```

So how do I get the second column under the 'div' element that has the same 'className' as the first column?

Is there a way to find all then select [0] and [1] and assign them to different variables or the same? I would like for all the links to end up under the same variable. I also tried using

```
find_next
```

but it returns this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify'
```

Which leads me to believe that when I try to assign the content to the second variable it results in nothing happening. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use find_all instead of find and select the second index.

```
columns=content.find_all('div',{'class': 'className'})
print(columns[1].text)
print(columns[0].text)
```

Comment: That did it. Accepted your answer. How would I place them in the same "column"?

Comment: Do you mean same index?

Comment: You could append them to an empty list and concatenate them.